# Remove Salesforce lightning attributes from a managed package

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

It seems we're not able to remove attributes from a managed package.

Failed to save xxx.design: You can't remove design attributes 'XXX' when the component implements a Lightning Page interface.: Source

What is a workaround to fix this issue on Salesforce?